# Problems with return type deduction for normal functions?

Tags: c++, c++14

At the end of Eric Niebler's Proto-0x talk there is a discussion about **C++1y** features. When discussing [return type deduction for normal functions](http://youtu.be/JF6YM0XzHnE?t=1h13m40s), he says that, (with the current **C++1y** spec, I suppose), he won't be able to use return type deduction for normal functions (which would allow him to replace some of his `RETURN try_call` *cleverness*). I hope I got this point right. Please correct me if I didn't.

Sadly, the rationale behind this assertion wasn't captured in the video (I can't barely hear anything). The only reason I am able to hear is that functions are not deduced to be `noexcept`. But it seems there is another more important reason.

Does anyone know the reason or is able to transcribe the discussion?

Comment: Why you use type deduction for normal functions? You should know the return type. Type deduction is usually used when you do NOT know the return type, i.e. when input type is template-determined: `template <typename A, typename B> auto Sum(const A&, const B&) -> decltype(A(0)+B(0))`

Comment: C++14 will support return type deduction

Comment: @XiaogeSu I don't understand your answer. For the why question, see the video. Furthermore, there are things that you cannot do without return type deduction, like returning a lambda from a function.

Comment: @gnzlbg: You can return a lambda in a `std::function` just fine.

Comment: @aaronman that's why I've tagged the question with c++1y.

Comment: @NicolBolas you can return a `std::function` _that stores a lambda_, but not a lambda.

Comment: @gnzlbg: You tagged it with C++11. C++11 is not "any higher version of C++". It's a *specific* version of C++, released in 2011.

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry for that, I thought I had used the c++1y tag!

Comment: @gnzlbg: You did.  Rapptz removed if for some reason.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: He probably removed it for the same reason I did: the talk is about C++11, not C++14.

Comment: @NicolBolas The talk is about C++11, but the question in the talk is about using return type deduction for normal functions, which is a C++1y feature, isn't it? I can't barely hear anything in that part of the video.

Comment: @gnzlbg: He's talking about what he would *like* to be able to do. But his code is written against C++11, so he *can't* do that. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @NicolBolas In the discussion they are talking also about c++1y (relaxed constexpr and return type deduction). He says he would like to use return type deduction for normal functions in C++1y (to replace his RETURN try_call hacks). For a reason I cannot hear due to the video quality, he says that (with the current spec, I suppose) he won't be able to, and that most of boost developers won't be able either. My question is, why did he said that? what is their rationale? what is wrong with the current spec?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Your interpretation of what he is saying does not fit at all.  He says he won't be able to use that feature, and that it's very sad.  What's very sad?  That he won't be able to use the feature until everyone else can use it?  Yes, his code is written against C++11.  But when C++1y is standardized, he will rewrite the code against that.

Comment: Perhaps a comment on that video will get you a response (eventually).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, I removed it because the talk was about C++11 and not C++14. He edited the body after I removed it though to add more information.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought that the title (a C++1y feature "name") and the c++1y tag were clear enough at the beginning, but then decided to make it more clear that the question was not about a C++11 talk, but about a C++1y discussion that happened at the end of the C++11 talk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without watching the video (if the relevant part is inaudible there's no point anyway!) I would hazard a guess that the problem is that return type deduction doesn't allow SFINAE tricks to be used in the return type. The RETURNS macro (which comes from David Abrahams) is used like this:

```
    template<typename T>
      auto foo( T&& t ) RETURNS( some-expression-using-t );
```

Where that expands to:

```
    template<typename T>
      auto foo( T&& t ) noexcept(noexcept( some-expression-using-t ))
      -> decltype( some-expression-using-t )
      { return some-expression-using-t; }
```

This deduces the return type and exception specification from the expression, and also SFINAE causes the function to be removed from the overload set if `some-expression-using-t` is not a valid expression.

However in C++1y re-writing it like this to use return type deduction:

```
    template<typename T>
      decltype(auto) foo( T&& t )
      { return some-expression-using-t; }
```

You lose the automatic exception-specification and the SFINAE behaviour. To get those features back you have to write out the `some-expression-using-t` part multiple times again (or use the macro) and not use the (otherwise very nice) return type deduction feature.

N.B. Concepts Lite will provide a better alternative to the SFINAE feature, but we might still want `noexcept(auto)` to get the automatic exception-specification behaviour back again.

Comment: I think `decltype(auto)` _might_ provide something like `noexcept(auto)` by default. Combining RETURNS with sfinae for expressions is clever indeed.

Comment: @gnzlbg, I don't think so, see the **noexcept** section of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html

Comment: I hope so, or we'll be stuck with the macro solution. The problems in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3207.htm are a bit scary but they would only apply to new code.